# Python calculator - How can I make this better

Tags: python

im pretty new to programming. I made this calculator in python and I was wondering how can I  make it more efficient because it seems a bit inefficient to me.  I'm still really unfamiliar with python and some programming concepts so it would be nice to get an idea of different ways I may do this.  Perhaps there is a better way for me to set up the functions or maybe a way that they can be put into different classes? 
Thanks for any responses

```
def add():
    a = int(raw_input("Enter a number!: \n"))
    b = int(raw_input("Enter a number!: \n"))
    c = a + b
    if a + b == c:
        print c 
        menu()
    return c 
def sub():
    a = int(raw_input("Enter a number!: \n"))
    b = int(raw_input("Enter a number!: \n"))
    c = a - b
    if a - b == c:
        print c 
        menu()
    return c 

def mul():
    a = int(raw_input("Enter a number!: \n"))
    b = int(raw_input("Enter a number!: \n"))
    c = a * b
    if a * b == c:
        print c 
        menu()
    return c 

def div():
    a = float(raw_input("Enter a number!: "))
    b = float(raw_input("Enter a number!: "))
    c = a / b
    if a / b == c:
        print c 
        menu()
    return c 

def square():
    a = int(raw_input("Enter a number!: \n"))
    c = a * a
    if a * a == c:
        print c 
        menu()
    return c 

def menu():
    print """
    1. Addition
    2. Subtraction
    3. Multiplication
    4. Division
    5. Square
    6. Exit
    """

    choices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    choice = int(raw_input("Enter a number!: \n"))

    while True:
        if choice == 1:
            print add()
        elif choice == 2:
            print sub()
        elif choice == 3:
            print mul()
        elif choice == 4:
            print div()
        elif choice == 5:
            print square()
        elif choice == 6:
            exit()
        else:
            for choose in choices:
                if choice != choices:
                    print "Please enter a number 1 - 6!"
                    menu()


menu()
```

Comment: Your program is reasonably efficient. It spends most of its time waiting for the user and the calculations it performs are simple and fast. Certainly you should never notice the program responding less than instantly on any computer from the past decade. What in particular do you think is inefficient?

Comment: one common idea is to try and eliminate the repetition... eg your `add` `sub` `mul` `div` all contain almost exactly the same code with just the operator changing... so the idea would be to just have one function which takes "the user's input" and the "operator to use" as arguments

Comment: Try codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: you don't need any classes here anyway

Comment: Thanks, great to know everyone. I will try to reduce the repetition and perhaps organize things more concisely and also give codereview a look since this kind of question probably belongs there rather than here.  What I thought was inefficient is maybe the way it is structured, but I have since gotten some answers to guide me on that

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of `if a + b == c:` and similar lines in the other functions. Also, calling `menu()` inside your calculation functions is not good design: it unnecessarily makes your program recursive, and recursion in Python is generally not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things which you are repeating in all the functions. Like asking user to input two numbers a & b using raw_input multiples times. They can be put into another method say `getTwoNumbers()` which will take two inputs from user and return the two numbers. This method (i.e `getTwoNumbers()`)need to be invoked in the function(s) which is/are performing binary operation. Also you are storing the result into another variable c, which can be ommited and hence comparison with binary operation with the variable c is also not required. It is better if you can perform `return a+b` or `return a-b` etc, based on the current binary operation you want to perform.

Answer (score 0):

First, in the `else` case where the user entered an invalid menu number, you don't need these lines:

```
        for choose in choices:
            if choice != choices:
```

After all, you already know `choice` is not valid.

Second, when the user enters `6`, rather than `exit()` you should just `return`.  The program will still end.  It's often considered "rude" for a function to call `exit()` directly--let the caller decide what to do when the function ends.

Third, you don't need to call `menu()` when your operators succeed.  It's strange that you do, since `menu()` contains its own infinite loop anyway.  It's just redundant.

Finally, you can collapse all the two-argument math functions into one, by passing in the actual operation as an argument.  The `operator` module makes this easier.

Putting all these ideas together, here's the new code:

```
import operator

def dobinaryop(op):
    a = float(raw_input("Enter a number!: \n"))
    b = float(raw_input("Enter a number!: \n"))
    return op(a, b)

def square():
    a = float(raw_input("Enter a number!: \n"))
    return a * a

def menu():
    while True:
        print """
    1. Addition
    2. Subtraction
    3. Multiplication
    4. Division
    5. Square
    6. Exit
    """

        choice = int(raw_input("Enter a number!: \n"))

        if choice == 1:
            print dobinaryop(operator.add)
        elif choice == 2:
            print dobinaryop(operator.sub)
        elif choice == 3:
            print dobinaryop(operator.mul)
        elif choice == 4:
            print dobinaryop(operator.div)
        elif choice == 5:
            print square()
        elif choice == 6:
            exit()
        else:
            print "Please enter a number 1 - 6!"

menu()
```

You could streamline this even further by putting the various operators into a list and indexing by `choice`, but that's getting slightly arcane for not much benefit given you only have four such operators, plus two special cases and bounds checking.

Answer (score -1):

Put functions and related index in a dictionary. Use that dictionary to decide which function to execute.

And get duplicated part of every function out. I think these solutions will get your code better.